# existence of some algebraic closure

Tags: field-theory

I was curious somethings when I studied algebraic closure in Hungerford's algebra.

I know that every field has an algebraic closure. But I have the following question.

Let $K$ be a field and $F$ an algebraic extension of $K$. Then is there an algebraic closure of $K$ containing $F$?

I know that its answer is "yes", but I have difficulty to say its reason logically.

Roughly, I can only say that 'because every field has an algebraic closure, and any two algebraic closures of $K$ are $K$-isomorphic'.
Is my answer reasonable?
If not, please tell me the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is on the right track. Consider the algebraic closure $F'$ of $F$. Then $K \subset F \subset F'$, and since $F'$ is algebraic over $F$ and $F$ is algebraic over $K$, $F'$ is also algebraic over $K$. Moreover, $F'$ is algebraically closed. This shows that $F'$ is an algebraic closure for $K$ which contains $F$. Because the algebraic closure is unique up to isomorphism, we can say that $F'$ is contained in *the* algebraic closure of $K$. That is, given any other algebraic closure $K'$ of $K$, we can embed $F$ into $K'$ by restricting an isomorphism between $F'$ and $K'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very easy answer, but it's nice!

Comment: @NH.Jeong glad it helped =) One thing to add is that the embedding of $F$ into $K'$ will not in general be unique -- said otherwise, an algebraic closure contains many different "copies" of $F$.

Comment: Really? If you give an example for that, it would be big aid to me. Would you tell me such example?

Comment: @NH.Jeong for example, if you consider $K=\mathbb Q$, you can adjoin $a=\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 3$, which is root of the irreducible polynomial $x^4-10x^2+1$. The element $b=\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is also a root of the given polynomial, and there is an nontrivial automorphism of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ which $a$ to $b$ and $b$ to $a$. This automorphism also restricts to the identity on $\mathbb Q$. The fact that this automorphism exists is related to the fact that they are both roots of the same irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Studying different embeddings of algebraic extensions of a given field into the algebric closure of the field is a big topic, subsumed by [Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory). You might find this something interesting to study in the future!

Comment: Oh I see. I appreciate your help. Thank you~

Answer (score 2):

Take an algebraic closure $\overline F$ of $F$. Then $\overline F$ is algebraic over $K$ and is algebraically closed, hence an algebraic closure of $K$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is big help to me!